# Detect a view is partially visible inside a RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android

Is there a good way to detect or even better, get notified, when a View of interest inside the ViewHolder has moved outside of the window bounds (was scrolled off or partially scrolled off)?

I'm thinking that one option is to set a scroll listener on the `RecyclerView` and check my `LayoutManager` for `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()` etc, and calculate which views are no longer visible. Something like:

```
private RecyclerView.OnScrollListener mScrollListener = new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        calculateVisibility();
    }
};
```

where `calculateVisibility()` would run on every scroll event, but this will only give me visibility of my ViewHolder positions, not actual ViewHolders or individual views inside those view holders. Which means I need to then lookup from my layout manager the actualy layout for the position, then measure individual views inside the view holder. Something like:

```
private void calculateVisibility() {
    if (!isAdded() || !getUserVisibleHint() || mAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == -1
            && mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == -1
            && mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == -1
            && mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == -1) {
        return;
    }
    int firstPartiallyVisiblePosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
    int lastPartiallyVisiblePosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

    View v = mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstPartiallyVisiblePosition);
    for (v instanceof MySpecialView) {
        boolean visible = isViewVisible(v);
        // do stuff based on visibility
    }
}
```

This feels like it's going to be very inefficient.

Methods I could find inside the adapter seem to be more related to recycling and detaching, which won't happen if you simply scroll the view of the screen.

Maybe someone has done something similar?

Comment: What are your reasons for wanting to do this?

Comment: I have ExoPlayer playing videos inside RecyclerView. There can be multiple videos inside a ViewHolder. Once at least one of the is scrolled off the screen, I need to stop the player and release the resources.

Comment: Perhaps `View.getVisibility()` is more efficient. I'm not sure if this will completely satisfy your use-case.

Comment: Of course, where efficiency is concerned, you should actually implement a solution and actually measure run-times before concluding anything.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `getVisibility()` only returns one of `GONE|VISIBLE|INVISIBLE` which do not take into account view position on it's parent.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately getVisibility is not going to help me.. And measuring on run-time - true visibility on screen inside a scrollable view is not a static value, as in, visibility in viewport changes with scrolling, therefore not sure how I can achieve that...

Comment: @NameSpace sorry I'm not sure I understand. Even if the backing data position in the list is the same, howe can I grab the view holder without doing `findViewByPosition`?

Comment: ok my bad, I misread the question to be when an itemView of interest is no longer fully visible instead of a view within the itemView/ViewHolder.

Answer (score 2):

In case this is useful to anyone, this is what I ended up doing:

```
  private void calculateVisibility() {
    if (!isAdded() || !getUserVisibleHint() || mAdapter == null
            || mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (mLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == -1
            && mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == -1
            && mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == -1
            && mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() == -1) {
        return;
    }
    int findFirstVisibleItemPosition = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    int findLastVisibleItemPosition = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

    int [] positions = {findFirstVisibleItemPosition, findLastVisibleItemPosition};
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    mRecyclerView.getDrawingRect(scrollBounds);
    int location[] = new int[2];
    for (int position : positions) {
        viewHolder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(
                mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(position));
        viewHolder.getMySpecialView().getLocationInWindow(location);

        if (location[1] < 0 || location[1] > scrollBounds.bottom) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.